# How to output a vector of vector of floats?

Tags: c++, iterator

Very basic question, but I am having trouble understanding how I can output this.

I have a

```
vector< vector<float> > distance_table;
```

It is filled with all sorts of numbers in it. Now I want to output these.

Here is the code I have:

```
 vector< vector<float> > :: iterator row;
    vector<float> ::iterator col;
    for (row = distance_table.begin(); row !=distance_table.end(); row++)
    {
        for (col = row->begin(); col !=row->end(); col++)
        {
            cout << distance_table[row][col] <<endl;

        }

    }
```

The distance_table[row][col] is not working. It is obviously not the correct syntax. What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: That would be `*col`.

Answer (score 4):

You can not index with iterators. You either use integers or you use iterators but not both. You can dereference second iterator to get to the value within the particular vector.

```
vector< vector<float> > :: iterator row;
vector<float> ::iterator col;
for (row = distance_table.begin(); row !=distance_table.end(); row++)
{
    for (col = row->begin(); col !=row->end(); col++)
    {
        cout << *col << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`col` is an iterator over the inner vector, so you just need to dereference it to get the value:

```
cout << *col << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the range based for statement. For example

```
for ( const std::vector<double> &v : distance_table )
{
   for ( double x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

As for you code then instead iterators you should use indexed access to elements of the vector if you want to use the subscript operator.

For example

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>>::size_type size_type;

for ( size_type i = 0; i < distance_table.size(); i++ )
{
   for ( size_type j = 0; j < distance_table[i].size(); j++ )
   {
      std::cout << distance_table[i][j] << ' ';
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to do what you want. Note that this approach doesn't make use of iterators although that use of iterators is just as good.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector< vector<float> > distance_table;

    vector<float> a {0, 1};

    distance_table.push_back(a);
    for (auto i = 0; i <distance_table.size(); i++)
    {   
        for (auto j = 0; j <distance_table[i].size(); j++)
        {   
            cout << distance_table[i][j] << endl;

        }     
    }
}
```